# haskell system.random.mwc random integer

Tags: haskell, random, integer

I would like to use the library System.Random.MWC to generate a random integer in the range (0,30) . I can do this using the library System.Random :

```
import System.Environment

import System.IO.Unsafe                                        

import System.Random

p :: Integer -> Integer

p n = unsafePerformIO (getStdRandom (randomR (0 , n)))

main :: IO()

main = do
        print $! (p 30)}
```

But I am confused with System.Random.MWC.

Comment: `unsafePerformIO` isn’t really a good thing to use…

Comment: Have you read this? It has a good usage example. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.13.1.1/docs/System-Random-MWC.html

Comment: The example given is :
Prelude System.Random.MWC>  v <- uniformR (1, 52) gen
Prelude System.Random.MWC> v
2.2653285070310627
return double values not integer, and the command
--v <- uniform gen
return error message

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should not use `unsafePerformIO`. Generating a random number is an operation with a side effect, and therefore `p :: Integer -> Integer` is not a suitable type for a function generating a random `Integer` in the range of `0` to a given number.

Here's how to do it properly using `System.Random`:

```
import System.Random

p :: Integer -> IO Integer
p n = randomRIO (0 , n)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- p 30
  print x
```

For `mwc-random`, there's no generator for type `Integer`, but there is one for `Int`, which probably gives you a sufficiently large range. Here's an example:

```
import System.Random.MWC

p :: Int -> GenIO -> IO Int
p n gen = uniformR (0, n) gen

main :: IO ()
main = do
  gen <- createSystemRandom
  x <- p 30 gen
  print x
```

#### About doing this in GHCi

In your comment, you say that if you do something like this in GHCi, like this:

```
Prelude> import System.Random.MWC
Prelude System.Random.MWC> gen <- createSystemRandom 
Prelude System.Random.MWC> uniformR (0, 30) gen
27.823000834177332
```

Then it looks as if `uniformR` is generating a floating point number, not an integer. This is due to "defaulting" of overloaded numeric types which is applied in Haskell, which is one of the stranger and trickier corners of the Haskell language and can be somewhat confusing. The type of `uniformR` is:

```
uniformR :: (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimMonad m, Variate a) =>
            (a, a) -> Gen (Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState m) -> m a
```

In a GHCi context, the `PrimMonad` will be `IO`, so you can think of the type as the simpler:

```
uniformR :: Variate a => (a, a) -> GenIO -> IO a
```

So the result type can be an `IO a` for any instance of the `Variate` class. The `Variate` class has various instances defined in the `mwc-random` package. As you're typing this into GHCi, there's no type signature or context that would restrict the `a`. So which of the many options should GHC choose? That's what defaulting specifies. The standard defaulting order in Haskell is `Integer`, then `Double`. There's no instance for `Variate Integer`, so the instance for `Variate Double` is chosen. If neither instance would exist, a type error would be reported. You can always override defaulting by giving a type annotation. So here, you could do

```
Prelude System.Random.MWC> uniformR (0, 30) gen :: IO Int
25
```

to specifically specify that you want an `Int`, not a `Double`.

Comment: Thanks , this clarify how to use this library.